# How do I use a string name instead of a variable?

Tags: c++, c, function, variables

Suppose I have the following func and want to compare `field` as variable and `value` as value. How can I do it?

```
bool ReadFile::compareField(string field, string value)
{
    if (field == "value")
}
```

Comment: What language?  Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: It's related to C/C++. @OliCharlesworth

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about C++, then the answer is: you can't.  Variables are a compile-time thing; they don't exist at run-time.

If you want to access parameters as strings, then you might consider using e.g. a `std::map`:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, int> params;

public:
    MyClass()
    {
        params["height"] = 165;
        params["weight"] = 65;
        params["legs"]   = 2;
    }

    int getParam(const std::string &str) const
    {
        return params[str];
    }
};
```

Comment: oh,No, Suppose my variable exists before  it.and i just access it.your program initialize a new var.

Comment: @m_pahlevanzadeh: This a proof of concept.  Obviously, if you want to make it robust you will need to add error-handling, etc.

Comment: Yes,Of course you say correctly, but i didn't need to add in my implementation.So i wrote the following function that i put before here. @OliCharlesworth

Answer (score 0):

I changed the above func without map  to the following func:

```
bool ReadFile::compareField( string * field, string value){
int i;
string fieldName = *field;
//converting to lower case
for (i = 0; i< strlen(value.c_str());i++)
        value[i] = tolower(value[i]);
for (i = 0; i< strlen(fieldName.c_str());i++)
        fieldName[i] = tolower(fieldName[i]);
/////
cout << fieldName << endl;

if (strstr(fieldName.c_str(),value.c_str()) != NULL){
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

At first i convert to lowercase and then search with strstr func, But here is a nice note that i use address of that variable instead of its name.

Comment: I'm unfortunately out of downvotes, so -0 for this code. This seems an elaborate version of case-insensitive string comparsion, but by calling the two operands "field" and "value", you obscure the fact. The `field` parameter should be a const reference, and you are mixing C and C++ with no good effect (e.g. `strstr(fieldName.c_str(),value.c_str()) != NULL` instead of `fieldName == value`). The whole method should be replaced by `boost::iequals(field, value)`.

Comment: You mentioned to good case. I replace strstr() with strObj.substr() thank you for your attention.@thiton